# plt.show() crops the figure to the axes

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to place an `Axes` within a `Figure` so that the `Axes` has substantial margins within the `Figure`.

When I render it with `plt.savefig`, it works fine:

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(4, 4))
ax1 = fig.add_axes([.3, .3, .1, .1])
ax2 = fig.add_axes([.6, .6, .1, .1])
plt.savefig("my figure", facecolor="grey")
```

[image]

But when I render it with `plt.show`, it crops the `Figure` to any contained `Axes`:

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(4, 4), facecolor="grey")
ax1 = fig.add_axes([.3, .3, .1, .1])
ax2 = fig.add_axes([.6, .6, .1, .1])
plt.show()
```

[image]

How do I stop `plt.show` from cropping the `Figure`, and instead show the true size of the `Figure`, like `plt.savefig` does?

Comment: 1. You save the file with `figsize=(10, 10)` and you show the image with `figsize=(4, 4)`, so there is at least one difference in size coming from. 2. Are only running the code you posted? Because this is not happening for me...

Comment: Good catch, apologies -- that was just a typo in the source though, which I've fixed. What behaviour are you seeing exactly? Is `plt.show` not cropping?

Comment: `plt.show` is not cropping on my system. Python `3.6.8` and matplotlib `3.1.0`. Does changing `figsize` affect the output?

Comment: matplotlib `2.2.3`, Python `3.7.0`. Within a Jupyter Notebook if that makes a difference. I'm surprised matplotlib is so old; I'll update and see if that resolves this.

Comment: @VishnuDasu I'm now updated to matplotlib `3.1.0` -- the problem persists. Changing the figure size simply produces a scaled up version of the figure I posted.

Comment: @Denziloe I get the same output as you did within a Jupyter Notebook. The solution in the question marked as duplicate seems to work, have a look.